# Ubuntu Server 20.04 randomly crashing

Tags: server

At least once a day my home server crashes. This is a recent build, (7/16/2020, with all new hardware etc).

Machine Specs:

- AMD Ryzen 5 3400G with Radeon Vega Graphics
- B450 AORUS M
- 32 GB RAM DIMM DDR4
- 1TB SSD M2
- 2 6TB HDD
- 1 TB HDD
- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

I'm currently running via APT the following apps

- Roon Server
- Docker (the snap version has been uninstalled)
- Samba
- Restic for backups

On Docker Im running

- PiHole (I have turned off dnsresovler so its not a port issue there)
- Portainer
- Plex
- Resilio Sync

I am not able to find much in the logs but did come across the following section of the log that piqued my interest after the s system crashed this afternoon.  Doesn't tell me much but maybe someone here can help get me headed in the right direction.

For some reason I can't copy or paste the actual log to represent it as I'm seeing it. I've included a screen shot. In short it looks like its doing something with docker, then i get a bunch of (bad memory locations?) `<0x00>'

[image]

After it crashes I have zero ability to interact with the system.  The screen shows some information that I dont know what it means, or how to get at that data.  Maybe if it crashes again I'll take a photo with my phone.

I am not a linux/ubuntu expert (but pretty proficient with windows) and have been learning as I've been going since last Thursday when I built the machine and started installing ubuntu.

What Ive tried thus far.

- I have made sure there is disk space available. None of the drives are even remotely full (30%-40% utilized and RAM is showing 32GB available), and when it crashed recently it was under little to no load.  I was just streaming roon in another room.
- Docker seems to be running as expected. I did unintentionally install docker via apt vs snap, which was causing some problems, but i seem to have (I think) remedied that as I uninstalled both snap and apt version and ensured any remaining folders etc were removed.
- Bios shows all memory is loaded and recognized.
- `fdisk -l` shows no oddness and all drive look right size and right partitioning
- `free -h` shows 4Gi total for swap file but used 12mi, and RAM is showing 29 Gi total, and 28Gi available.
- `dmesg` shows this error shows up quite a few times. Searching isn't yielding too much luck.

```
    [ 2328.925902] BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: 0000000000c045c7
    [ 2328.925905] #PF: supervisor write access in kernel mode
    [ 2328.929589] RIP: 0010:fsnotify+0x63/0x3d0
    [ 2328.933164] #PF: error_code(0x0002) - not-present page
```

Any help/ideas anyone might have is greatly appreciated, this is getting somewhat annoying.

Edit: Per suggestions of @heynnema

`sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`  returns `F50`

`sysctl vm.swappiness` returns `vm.swapiness = 60`

`sudo lshw -C memory`:

```
*-firmware
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: F50
       date: 11/27/2019
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 9
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 32GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1866 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-3200C16-8GVKB
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1866MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1866 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-3200C16-8GVKB
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1866MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1866 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-3200C16-8GVKB
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 2
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1866MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1866 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-3200C16-8GVKB
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 3
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1866MHz (0.5ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: b
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 384KiB
       capacity: 384KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: c
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 2MiB
       capacity: 2MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: d
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 4MiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
```

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo lshw -C memory`. Also, have you run `memtest`?

Comment: Whenever you respond to a request for more info, make sure to send a comment that starts with @heynnema (in my case), so that the user gets notified. I almost missed your question updates.

Comment: @heynnema  I'm running `memtest` at the moment. Its been running for an hour or so, and has found several errors.  110 errors on pass 1 of 4.  Once this is done I"ll run the next command you recommended. 
My apologies, i tagged you in the initial post because I couldn't put that much text in a reply .

Comment: Before troubleshooting the memtest/memory errors, we need to update the BIOS, as that might fix the memory problem. Report back.

Comment: memtest ran and it had errors Result was 'Fail'

```
Test # Tests Passed Errors
Test 1 [Address test, own address, 1 CPU] 3/4 (75%) 8
Test 3 [Moving inversions, ones & zeroes] 2/4 (50%) 88
Test 6 [Block move, 64-byte blocks] 3/4 (75%) 14
Test 7 [Moving inversions, 32-bit pattern] 2/4 (50%) 24
Test 8 [Random number sequence] 3/4 (75%) 23
Test 9 [Modulo 20, ones & zeros] 3/4 (75%) 1
Test 10 [Bit fade test, 2 patterns, 1 CPU] 0/4 (0%) 422
```

So, based on this are all of the RAM bad, is it the motherboard? Where do I go next with troubleshooting.

Comment: I have also updated the BIOS to F51 and am running another memtest to see if it was BIOS related. @heynnema

Comment: Good on the BIOS update. If memtest fails again, you don't have to run it all the way. But contact me first before the next step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're having page fault errors.

**BIOS**

Gigabyte B450 AORUS M

You have BIOS version F50.

There's a newer BIOS available, version F51f, and it can be downloaded [here](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/B450-AORUS-M-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios).

Update video available [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ze4Dg11W3hU).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**memtest**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Update #1:**

`memtest` has failed. We'll first update the BIOS, then retest with `memtest`, and troubleshoot memory if errors still occur.

**Update #2:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Update #3:**

After updating the BIOS, `memtest` still failed. We tested various pairs of DIMMs in slots 1 & 2, and they all passed `memtest`. I believe that there is a compatibility problem with the Ryzen CPU, and the G.SKILL DIMMs, when all four DIMMs are installed, so we swapped them for Corsair DIMMs.

`memtest` now runs all 4/4 tests with no errors!

Reference: CPU Support list https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/B450-AORUS-M-rev-10/support#support-cpu

Reference: RAM Support list https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/B450-AORUS-M-rev-10/support#support-doc

Comment: I stopped the mem test after it was in 3/4 and already had over 500 errors.  The RAM is all same manufacturer, size and speed. Is there somethign I can get from the test to help me determine which bar of memory might be bad?

Comment: @BigDubb Pull the AC power. Then hold down the power button for 10 seconds. Do this every time we move memory. Pull RAM sticks in slots 4_3 & 4_4 (as per the image above) and rerun `memtest`. Report back for the next step.

Comment: @BigDubb  Status please...

Comment: The mem test just finished.  4/4 on passing with 0 errors.  So, one can assume its one of the two bars taken out, right?  Should I put one of them back in one of in 4_2 or 4_1 and re-run the memtest?

Comment: @BigDubb Good! Progress! Yes, **potentially** one of the DIMMs removed from slots 3 or 4 is bad. So yes, remove the DIMM from 4_2, put it in the **good** pile, and stick one of the 3/4 DIMMs into 4_2 and rerun memtest. If memtest runs ok, then take 4_2 and put it into the **good** pile, and take the remaining 3/4 DIMM and stick it into 4_2 and rerun memtest. Report back.

Comment: @BigDubb Just to get ahead of ourselves, if both 3/4 DIMMs pass when they're in slot 4_2, there's a possibility that one of the DIMMs wasn't seated properly into its slot. We'll know if we return all of the DIMMs to the three slots, re-seat the DIMM in 4_1, and memtest runs ok.

Comment: @BigDubb Status please...

Comment: I re-ran memtest with both the RAM that was in 4_4 and 4_4 both passed 4/4 zero errors.  I am now in the process of testing with all four slots filled with RAM. I also ensured that each was correctly. This test took 9 hrs last time so I wont have an update until later this evening.

Comment: @BigDubb You re-seated the 4_1 DIMM, yes? Let me know the final memtest results.

Comment: Yes I re-seated the 4_1 RAM as well.  Double and triple checked to make sure everything was seated correctly. If this solves the problem I will definitely mark as the correct answer. Thanks again.

Comment: - Its been running for the better part of 7 hrs. Still on pass 1 and looks as if its stuck. Should I restart the memtest or does this give us enough information to pursue something else?

Comment: i restarted memtest. its already further than it was previously and has encountered several errors on pass 1.  Did we just determine if it was the mobo?

Comment: @BigDubb Maybe. Remove DIMMs slot 3 & 4. Move the DIMMs from slots 1 & 2 into slots 3 & 4. Rerun memtest. If it fails, it may be a bad slot or mobo. We'll see. Is the mobo under warranty? Are you 100% sure that the RAM is the correct spec for this mobo and CPU? Ryzens are funny with memory.

Comment: @BigDubb See the memory support lists at https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/B450-AORUS-M-rev-10/support#support-doc

Comment: @BigDubb Your RAM may not be on the above approved list.

Comment: There several lists there.   AMD Matisse CPU, AMD Picasso APU, AMD Raven Ridge, AMD Summit Ridge CPU and Pinnacle Ridge.  The RAM I have is approved for the Picasso APU, but I'm not seeing it for any of the other specs.  The RAM I am currently running is G.SKILL 16GB 2X8GB DDR4 3200.  Ill swap out the memory nonetheless and retest.  When I bought this hardware at microcenter, I was told that this would all work. So I trusted the sales person. caveat emtpor I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111226/discussion-between-heynnema-and-bigdubb).

Comment: @BigDubb Status please...